# PostgreSQL: Sequentially number existing column foreign key wise

Tags: postgresql

I have 'patient' and 'visit' tables with one-to-many relation (one patient can have many visits). The 'visit' table has a 'visit_date' column. I added a 'visit_number' integer column to the 'visit' table for numbering visits chronologically. Now i need to insert values in this column sequentially starting from 1 for each patient. So for say, two patients having two and three visits respectively, the visit numbering should be 1, 2 for the first patient and 1, 2, 3 for the second one. How can this be done from the PostgreSQL command line?

I am using PostgreSQL 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to add a column that can be calculated.  What happens if you have to delete a visit, change the date of a visit, insert an older visit, or update the patient id?  These cases can be handled with triggers, but it gets messy.  It would likely be better to add a view:

```
CREATE VIEW test as
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (partition by patient_id order by visit_date) as visit_number
FROM visit;
```